# Executar código dentro do event listener

Tags: javascript

Olá! Como eu executo um código dentro do `event listener` programaticamente?

**Exemplo:**

```
document.getElementById("voltar").addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("teste");
}, true);
```

Quero executar o `alert` do `addEventListener`. Tentei setar um nome no `function()`, e chamar `alerta_listener()` mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode abstrair o conteúdo dessa função, e criar outra, a chamando quando desejar.
Ex:

```js
 function Teste(){
    alert("teste");
}

document.getElementById("voltar").addEventListener('click', function() {
  Teste();
}, true);
```

```html
<button type="button" id="voltar">Voltar</button>
```

Ou, caso utilize JQuery, pode disparar o evento utilizando o [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Ex: `$(elemento).trigger("click");`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode executar o `alert` (ou qualquer outro código dentro do `event listener`) criando um `trigger click()` para o evento:

```
document.getElementById("voltar").click();
```

```js
document.getElementById("voltar").addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("teste");
}, true);

document.getElementById("voltar").click();
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Voltar" id="voltar" />
```

**Pode também usar uma função separada:**

```
function alerta(){
    alert("teste");
}

document.getElementById("voltar").addEventListener('click', alerta, true);
```

```js
function alerta(){
 alert("teste");
}

document.getElementById("voltar").addEventListener('click', alerta, true);
```

```html
<button type="button" id="voltar">Voltar</button>
```